# Recursion in Python/Merge Sort/Call by Reference

Tags: python-3.x, mergesort

My apologies, I'm new to StackOverFlow & Python.  I've written a code for Merge_Sort but it's not running as the values of arrays are getting lost while returning from recursion calls.
Coding Environment: Python3.x
OS: Linux ( Ubuntu 18.04)
**Below is my code:**

```
class sort: 
def __init__(self, arr, n):
    self.arr = arr
    self.n = n   
def __init__(self, arr, m, n):
    self.arr = arr
    self.m = m
    self.n = n
    arrS = arr.copy()
    arrL = [0] * (n - int((m + n)/2) + 1)
    arrR = [0] * (n - (m + 1))
def Merge_sort(self,arr,first,last):
    mid = int((first + last) / 2)
    arrMain = arr[first:last+1]
    arrLeft = arr[first:mid+1]
    arrRight = arr[mid+1:last+1]
    arrL = [0] * (mid - first + 1)
    arrR = [0] * (last - mid + 1)
    arrN = [0] * ( last - first + 1)
    if first < last:
        #Sort Left Array
        self.Merge_sort(arr, first, mid)
        #Sort Right Array
        self.Merge_sort(arr, mid+1, last)
        #I defined the below 3 variables while debugging to view the list
        arrL = arr[first:mid+1]
        arrR = arr[mid+1:last+1]
        print("Left Array: " + str(arrL))
        print("Right Array: " + str(arrR))
        x = len(arrL)
        y = len(arrR)
        i = j = k = 0
        while i < x and j < y:
            if (arrL[i] <= arrR[j]):
                arrN[k] = arrL[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arrN[k] = arrR[j]
                j += 1
            # end-if#001
            k += 1
        while (i < x):
            arrN[k] = arrL[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while (j < y):
            arrN[k] = arrR[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
        arr = arrN.copy()
        print("Merged Array:" + str(arr))
        return arrN
    #End-if#001
from Sort import sort
arr = [7, 5, 4 ,9, 3, 2 , 0, 1, 6, 8]
n = 0
sort4 = sort(arr, 0, int(len(arr)))
sort4.arr = arr.copy()
sort4.Merge_sort(sort4.arr, 0, int(len(arr)) - 1)
```

*Input of the program: arr = [7, 5, 4 ,9, 3, 2 , 0, 1, 6, 8]

Output of the program:  Left Array: [7, 5, 4, 9, 3]  Right Array: [2, 0, 1, 6, 8]

Merged Array:[2, 0, 1, 6, 7, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3]*
At the end of program it just seems to merge my original array.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: My apologies for the messy looking code, this was my first question. So, wasn't really aware how to ask the question. Also I found the issue with my code, it's mentioned in Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just to notify you, the problem is resolved. I wasn't returning the values correctly. Below is my code just for the reference.

```
def Merge_sort(self,arr,first,last):

    mid = int((first + last) / 2)

    arrMain = arr[first:last+1]
    arrLeft = arr[first:mid+1]
    arrRight = arr[mid+1:last+1]
    arrL = [0] * (mid - first + 1)
    arrR = [0] * (last - mid + 1)
    arrN = [0] * ( last - first + 1)

    if first < last:

        #Sort Left Array
        arrL = self.Merge_sort(arr, first, mid)

        #Sort Right Array
        arrR = self.Merge_sort(arr, mid+1, last)

        #arrL = arr[first:mid+1]
        #arrR = arr[mid+1:last+1]
        print("Left Array: " + str(arrL))
        print("Right Array: " + str(arrR))
        x = int(len(arrL))
        y = int(len(arrR))

        i = j = k = 0

        while i < x and j < y:
            if (arrL[i] <= arrR[j]):
                arrN[k] = arrL[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arrN[k] = arrR[j]
                j += 1
            # end-if#001
            k += 1

        while (i < x):
            arrN[k] = arrL[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while (j < y):
            arrN[k] = arrR[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

        arr = arrN.copy()

        print("Merged Array:" + str(arr))

        return arrN
    #End-if#001
    return arrMain
```